# Using jquery to add new parent div tree

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jquery and find solution about this,

```
<div id="parent">
   <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
   <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
</div>
```

I want to make new parent div element after `<div id="parent">` and include all child from this parent to new parent using jquery, so the result html looks like below:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="newparent">
    <div class="child1">Child 1 Contents</div>
    <div class="child2">Child 2 Contents</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to solve this using jquery?

Comment: @heads5150 Your link doesn't work :P

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - @Madbreaks obviously I haven't tried the link... :-)

Comment: yes, thank you, already answered and solved this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery's [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) should do the trick:

```
$('#parent').wrapInner('<div class="newparent"></div>');
```