# Append a nested modal to an external div

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

How do I append this modal to an external div?

It's currently nested in a container with a fixed height. I need it to be outside that container.

Javascript that includes modal:

```
client.fetchQueryProducts({collection_id: collectionID}).then(function(products) {

// Products ==  the array of products within the parent div
for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
product = products[i];
var productHTML =   
'<div class="product" id="buy-button-'+i+'" data-product-id = "'+ product.id+'">'+
'<div class= "product">'+
'<div class = "image-overlay-container">' +
'</div>' +
'</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class = "product-modal" >'+
'<div class = "image-overlay-container">' +
'</div>' +
'<div class = "product-modal-close"></div>'+
'</div>';
```

Javascript that opens modal:

```
// open product modal
        $('.parent_div').on('click', '.image-overlay, .variant-image, .product-details', function(){
            console.log('clicked');
            $(this).parents('.product').find('.product-modal').show();
            if (!$('.product-modal-underlay').length) {
                $('body').append('<div class = "product-modal-underlay"></div>');
            }
        });
```

Html:

```
<div class= "parent_div">
<div class= "products">
<li>product 1</li>
<li>product 2</li>
<li>product 3</li>
</div>
</div>

<div class= "external_div">
//* where modal would append *//
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent_div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: could you show us the html that is concerned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jquery to add new parent div tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206012/using-jquery-to-add-new-parent-div-tree)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use JQuery's [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method (exemple from doc):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Using `.wrap()`, we can insert an HTML structure around the inner `<div>` elements like so:

```
$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

The new `<div>` element is created on the fly and added to the DOM. The result is a new `<div>` wrapped around each matched element:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="new">
        <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="new">
        <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help, the easiest work around was to add ScrollTop(0) to the parent div onClick.

Javascript:

```
// open product modal
        $('.parent_div').on('click', '.image-overlay, .variant-image, .product-details', function(){
            console.log('clicked');
            $('.parent_div').scrollTop(0);
            $(this).parents('.product').find('.product-modal').show();
            if (!$('.product-modal-underlay').length) {
                $('body').append('<div class = "product-modal-underlay"></div>');
            }
        });
```